# Did the "Call 911 now!" sample in Skrillex's "First of the Year (Equinox)" come from a YouTube video?

Tags: sample, skrillex

In Skrillex's song "First of the Year (Equinox)" ([listen on Spotify](https://play.spotify.com/track/5i7fZq3chLyCHo3VeB6goD)), there is a sample of someone shouting, "Call 911 now!".

I've heard that this sample was taken from a YouTube video of some teenagers harassing a woman until she tried to call the police. Is this true?

Comment: Dunno, but the "Yes, OH MY GOD!" from Scary Monsters came from a YouTube video of a girl stacking cups, so it's entirely possible he used the same medium for that sample too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some quick gewgulls, I'd say the answer is yes.

[Crazy Lady yells at skaters Call 911 now original](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgGgmOy2av4)

BTW, as referenced above, here's the Scary Monsters original sample:

[7.00!!! OMG!!! NEW PB! OMG!! OMG!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j54yGxuk0yo)